# Yellow border in WPF when debugging in VS2022

Tags: wpf

I don't understand what the yellow border appeared around the WPF window when debugging in the Visual Studio 2022 preview. There is no such border in Visual Studio 2019.

[image]

Comment: The yellow border disappears when the setting is disabled:
Tools - Options - Debugging - XAML Hot Reload - Enable XAML Hot Reload.

Actually, the entire settings panel disappears, which is not quite what you need.

Comment: Did you try the non-preview version of Visual Studio 2022?